# Static and globals in C++

Tags: c++

Google's style guide refers to 'order-of-destructor issue' term.

(See the last sentence here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Static_and_Global_Variables#Static_and_Global_Variables).

What does this exactly mean?

p.s.: a quick search over the internet gave me nothing specific regarding this stuff

Comment: please dont post questions asking us to read an external document for you, learn to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's referring to the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).  If you have non-POD global objects with constructors or destructors, the order in which objects get initialized in different translation units (read: source files) is not easily controllable.